Definition clarification on topology regarding closed set
Recently started studying the subject Topology. It is my first time. I was going through the book Topology by Munkres. If $T$ is a topology on a set $X$, then every member of T is called an open set.
Next, they defined closed set. A subset A of X is closed if its complement is open.
For example, if we consider the $X=R$ and $A=[a,b]$ then its complement is $(-\infty ,a) \cup (b,\infty)$. And it is said that it is open.
MY DOUBT:
Is $(-\infty ,a) \cup (b,\infty)$ open just because it is union of open intervals or some other reason is behind it? Or is it because of the reason that it comes under definition of standard topology on $R$?
Kindly help. I think I am missing some point here. If this is already answered by some, then I am happy to receive the link of the same.

It sounds like you're asking for a proof that $(-\infty,a)\cup(b,\infty)$ is open in the standard topology on $\Bbb{R}$. Such a proof will depend on your definition of this topology, and there are a few different (equivalent) definitions. Which are you working with?

There are several ways to define what a topology is.  Defining it in terms of what all the open sets are is very common. But it would be equivalent to work with the family of closed sets.  The standard topology on $\mathbb R$ is a metric topology, so that most often one works with a distance between points to construct open sets.  This will be covered in the introductory sections of many textbooks.

"Is (−∞,a)∪(b,∞) open just because it is union of open intervals?"
Yes.  By definition, the topology $T$ on $\mathbb R$ is the set whose elements are the unions of open intervals.

It follows from the definition of topology and from the definition of the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$.
The usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$ is generated by the basis of open intervals $\{]a, b[ \mid a, b \in \mathbb{R}, a < b\}$.
The set $]-\infty, a[ \cup ]b, +\infty[$ is open because it is a union of elements of the basis of the topology, i.e., for each $c \in ]-\infty, a[ \cup ]b, +\infty[$, there is an element of the basis that is contained in $]-\infty, a[ \cup ]b, +\infty[$ and that contains $\{c\}$. If $c \in ]-\infty, a[ \cup ]b, +\infty[$, then $c \in ]-\infty, a[$ and $]c - 1, a[ \subseteq ]-\infty, a[$, or $c \in ]b, +\infty[$ and $]b, c + 1[ \subseteq ]b, +\infty[$.

Well strictly speaking there is a problem in the language that is used, when we say an "open interval" we mean an interval (a,b) but interestingly, in the typical topology that we define on $\mathbb{R}$ causes $(a,b)$ to be an open set.
There is no such thing as something that is an open set absolutely as much there is no such thing as a vector absolutely . You can only give something the name vector or open set relative to some other higher structure.
For example if you give $\mathbb{R}$ the smallest topology, that is the one having the empty set and $\mathbb{R}$ itself, then the open interval is no longer open set. It is simply, an open interval.
Maybe also worth nothing that defining the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$ is not quite a simple task. We first need to define auxillary concept of a basis for a topology, a topology generated by a basis and need some additional structure of $\mathbb{R}$, say for example either it's order or metric structure to define it.

A union of open sets, countable or not is always an open set. Without using this property, it is still very easy to see that it exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that for every $x \in ]-\infty , a[ \cup ]b,+\infty[$ : $$]x-\epsilon , x+\epsilon[ \subseteq ]-\infty , a[ \cup ]b,+\infty[ \quad \text{for some $(a,b) \in \mathbb{R}^2$}$$
